# Message is published from API #1, how do I create a listener in another API?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus

I've two APIs.
When one of the endpoints are called in API #1, message is sent to queue in Azure Service Bus.

API #2 should listen and make some changes in DB after this message appears in queue.

Message is sent to queue successfully.
Listener part doesn't work because the listener method is never called (and I do not understand how to call it).

Listener in API #2 :

```
public class MessageConsumer : IMessageConsumer
{
    const string connectionString = "stringTakenFromAzure";
    private static IQueueClient queueClient;
    private CartingDbContext context;
    public MessageConsumer(CartingDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

public async Task Consume()
{
    queueClient = new QueueClient(connectionString, "cartqueue");

    var options = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
    {
        MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
        AutoComplete = false
    };

    queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessageAsync, options);
    await queueClient.CloseAsync();
}

private async Task ProcessMessageAsync(Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var jsonBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
    var categoryItem = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CategoryItem>(jsonBody);

    //update item in DB. 
    var categoryItemInDb = context.CategoryItems.Where(x => x.Id == categoryItem.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    if (categoryItemInDb == null)
    {
        context.CategoryItems.Add(categoryItem);
    }
    else
    {
        context.CategoryItems.Update(categoryItem);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();

    await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
}

private static Task ExceptionReceivedHandler(ExceptionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

}

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMessageConsumer, MessageConsumer>();
```

Comment: Web API's aren't really good at listening for changes from a queue - they often get shut down when idle. Instead, an Azure Function might make more sense to use, or a console app in a Docker container, or an Azure WebJob. [This page compares Azure Functions and WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-compare-logic-apps-ms-flow-webjobs#webjobs-and-the-webjobs-sdk).

Comment: In your Consume method, you register the message handler, then immediately close the queue client. Seems like that wouldn't give anything very long to process.

Comment: @mason good point. But in my case, Consume method is not entered

Comment: Okay, so what's supposed to call the Consume method?

Comment: @mason that is what I don't get. I don't know whether I should use some third-party service like Hangfire or Azure has something similar

Comment: I mentioned several services you can leverage in Azure to do this. I suggest you research them, pick one, try it out, and see how it goes. Hangfire is for enqueuing background work, it's not really appropriate for continually running to process messages from a queue.

Comment: Just registering a your consumer with the DI container doesn't make something magically invoke methods on it: something needs to be running constantly to keep the queue client alive so that it can process those messages.

Comment: Consuming a Service Bus queues using an Azure Functions [is very simple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp). Best of all, you don't have to worry about where to host the app since it's serverless.